# Unusual problem in POST API call but I cannot find a way to solve it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a POST ajax call that is giving me some problems. When called, the browser does nothing for a few seconds and then the onError is called and returns a status of 0 (screenshot below). I have a couple of things trying to handle and display any errors (at the bottom) that might be happening, but neither of them seem to fire.

I have tried a few things (think I have included all of them below) and I have spent a few hours searching and trying them, but nothing seems to help or point at what the actual issue is. Plus with not being able to use dev tools on the browser, I feel like I have one hand tied behind my back.

Other points of information:

- I cannot access the developer tools of the browser, as they have been turned off by my company.
- If I run this this from a browser not on the network (say directly on the web server or my dev machine), it works as expected.
- This does not work in either Chrome or Edge (they are the only browser options I have).
- This is for a ring-fenced network at work and cannot be seen from the internet.
- I am using POST AJAX API calls else where on the same page and they work fine.
- jsonstr seems to be populating correctly as I can can stringify it and it looks correct.
- The page does not reload at any point.

**Javascript Function**

```
function saveHealthCheck() {
    var cID = $('#<%= hfHealthCheck.ClientID %>').val();
    var title = $('#<%= tbHealthCheckTitle.ClientID %>').val();
    var description = $('#<%= tbHealthCheckDescription.ClientID %>').val();
    var summary = $('#<%= tbHealthCheckSummary.ClientID %>').val();
    var detail = $('#<%= tbHealthCheckDetail.ClientID %>').val();
    var fix = $('#<%= tbHealthCheckFix.ClientID %>').val();
    var apps = [];

    $("#applicationList input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function (i) {
        apps.push(this.value);
    });

    var jsonstr = {
        "id": cID,
        "title": title,
        "description": description,
        "summary": summary,
        "detail": detail,
        "fix": fix
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/api/HealthChecks/") %>',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonstr,
        type: 'POST',
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert('Status: ' + xhr.status + '\nResponse: ' + xhr.responseText + '\nError: ' + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
          // Does stuff here and continues but is never reached
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

**Javascript Error handling**

```
window.onunhandledrejection = event => {
  alert(`UNHANDLED PROMISE REJECTION: ${event.reason}`);
};
    
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, col, error) {
   var extra = !col ? '' : '\ncolumn: ' + col;
   extra += !error ? '' : '\nerror: ' + error;

   alert("Error: " + msg + "\nurl: " + url + "\nline: " + line + extra);
};
```

Comment: Looks like a connection timeout at first glance. If the server has received the request but can't process it, the status field should be 4xx or 5xx.

Comment: @mcendu I don't think it is, as it consistently doing the same thing, but I am not having the same issue with any other AJAX calls I am doing on the page.

Comment: @PS Is this javascript inside Control? Or Page? Or separate file?

Comment: @dropoutcoder It is on the same page in a script block at the top of the page.

Comment: can you try to add this? `data: { field1: "hello", field2 : "hello2" },
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` (contentType, and make data not stringified)

Comment: @Dominik Tried that and it returns a 500 error (as expected). putting the data back and keeping the contentType, it goes back to the original problem. So I would suggest that I am having a data error. But if I run this on the server with the same data, it works.  Is it possible to limit the data length via group policy or something similar? Can it be over ruled locally on the page?

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs?

Comment: @Dominik Yes, but there is nothing there. The request isn't being received at the server. This is most definitely a client thing

Comment: there is no page name in URL section url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/api/HealthChecks/") %>',

Comment: @SudiptoBhattacharya Doesn't need to be. its a REST API call on a POST request with routing on the API.

Comment: Are you trying to connect using https? I seem to recall seeing something similar with certificate related issues.

Comment: @ste-fu No. We don't use https at all at present. I have mixed feelings about it and I do appreciate the advantages of using it, but its not my choice.